# Autofac fails to inject an object into the constructor, which it does resolve directly

Tags: autofac

I am experiencing a weird behavior with Autofac where I can use a container to resolve a type, say TypeA, but if I try resolve a type TypeB that needs TypeA object injected into the constructor, then container fails to resolve TypeA parameter!

Here is what my code looks like:

```cs
public class TypeA
{
}

public class TypeB
{
   public TypeB(TypeA obj)
   {
   }
}
```

This works:

```cs
var obj = container.Resolve<TypeA>();
```

But this does not:

```cs
var obj = container.Resolve<TypeB>();
```

It throws the following exception:

```
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyNamespace.TypeB' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'MyNamespace.TypeA obj' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyNamespace.TypeA)'.

Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.UseSingleConstructorActivation.AnonymousMethod__0(Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext, System.Action<Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext>)
    Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.BuildPipeline.AnonymousMethod__1(Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext)
    Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext, System.Action<Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext>)
    Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolvePipelineBuilder.BuildPipeline.AnonymousMethod__1(Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext)
    Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext, System.Action<Autofac.Core.Resolving.Pipeline.ResolveRequestContext>)
```

Strange thing is that I cannot reproduce this problem in a sample code that I can publish here. It works as expected in the sample project.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing that is causing my application code to behavior this way?

Thanks

Comment: Is TypeA registered in a more-nested scope than TypeB? I.e. TypeA is registered inside a BeginLifetimeScope call.

Comment: Namespace problem? Like you registered `Ns1.TypeA` but there's an `Ns2.TypeA` also and the wrong one is getting registered?

Comment: Hi @AlistairEvans, TypeA actually creates & maintains a nested child container itself and registers itself into it. Then it uses that nested child container to resolve other services that it needs. This is where the other service resolution is failing to resolve TypeA. But as mentioned in the description above, TypeA is able to resolve itself from the nested child container without an issue.

Comment: @AlistairEvans However, TypeB is registered in the parent container. Can a child container not resolve a type registered in the parent container that relies on the type that is registered in the child container?

Comment: @BSingh Could you update the sample code to reflect the scenario described in the above comment?